# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'transactions.length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i fix this , itry many ways to fix this code I can,t,

I want to store income and expense values in to array and then I want to display the balance. I use two buttons to store the income and expense value watch my code

**Income.js file**

```
export default function Income() {


let [{ transactions, addTransaction }] = useContext(TransactionContext)
const [newText, setText] = useState("")
let [newAmount, setAmount] = useState("")

// Transaction addition handler function
const additionHandler = () => {
  // If 0 is entered
  if (Number(newAmount) === 0) {
    alert("Please give an amount !")
    return false
  }

  addTransaction({
    amount: Number(newAmount),
    text: newText,
  })

  setText("")
  setAmount("")
}

const expenseHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (newAmount < 0) {
    alert("You can't enter negative value")
    setAmount("")
    setText("")
    return false
  }
  newAmount *= -1
  setAmount(newAmount)
  additionHandler()
}

const incomeHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (newAmount < 0) {
    alert("You can't enter negative value")
    setAmount("")
    setText("")
    return false
  }
  setAmount(newAmount)
  additionHandler()
}

// Function to calculate total income
const getIncome = () => {
  let income = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
    if (transactions[i].amount > 0) income += transactions[i].amount
  }
  return income
}

// Function to calculate total income
const getExpense = () => {
  let expense = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
    if (transactions[i].amount < 0) expense += transactions[i].amount
  }
  return expense
}

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animatable.View animation='zoomInUp'>

      <Text style={styles.logo}>Add Income</Text>
 <View style={styles.inputView} >
        <TextInput  
          onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}
          value={newText}

          />

      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView} >
        <TextInput  
          onChange={(event) => setAmount(event.target.value)}
          value={newAmount}
          />

      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputView} >
        <TextInput  
          >  ${getIncome() + getExpense()}</TextInput>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity rounded style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={() =>{
        incomeHandler

        // this.props.navigation.navigate('SignInScreen') 
        }} >

      <Text style={styles.loginText1} >Add Income</Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity rounded style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={() =>{
        expenseHandler

        // this.props.navigation.navigate('SignInScreen') 
        }} >

      <Text style={styles.loginText1} >Add Expense</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animatable.View>
  </View>
)
```

**MY TransactionProvider.js **

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import TransactionReducer from "../functions/TransactionReducer";

// Make an array of transaction objects
const initialTransactions = [];

// Create the context and export it
export const TransactionContext = createContext(initialTransactions);

// Create provider
export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Use Reducer
  let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(TransactionReducer, initialTransactions);

  //Function  Add transaction
  function addTransaction(transactionObj) {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TRANSACTION",
      payload: {
        text: transactionObj.text,
        amount: transactionObj.amount,
      },
    });
  }

  return (
    <TransactionContext.Provider
      value={{
        transactions: state,
        addTransaction,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TransactionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**TransactionReducer.js**

```
const TransactionReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
      return [action.payload, ...state];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default TransactionReducer;
```

please help me to fix this ... Thank you

Comment: Can you please create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that we can see how it works in practice?

Comment: I minimal my code please check it now

Comment: Did you try to initialize your state with let { transactions, addTransaction } = useContext(TransactionContext) ?

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to get the Length of Array of Objects in JavaScript

`// Make an array of transaction objects`
`const initialTransactions = [];`

`// Create the context and export it`
`export const TransactionContext = createContext(initialTransactions);`

do some like this: `Object.keys(myObj).length`

````
const transactions = [
  {
    text: "transaction text 1",
    amount: "2,000",
    id: "1",
  },

  {
   text: "transaction text 2",
    amount: "2,000",
    id: "2"
  },

  {
       text: "transaction text 3",
    amount: "4,000",
    id: "3"
  }
];

const totalProps = transactions.reduce((a, obj) => a + Object.keys(obj).length, 0);
console.log(totalProps);```
````